# meaning of "Well I think in many cases less is more"

Tags: meaning

[From the Oxford dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/less_is_more)

> **Well I think** in many cases less is more.

Is "well" here just a filler or part of a phrase? If latter, what does that mean?

If "well" here is just a filler, "I think" just means "in my opinion".

I could even consider "I think" and "in many cases" fillers as well. The whole sentence is just "less is more" without any other meaningful information.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's a filler, but I would have expected it to be followed by a comma.

Comment: The rest (as you put it) isn't purely filler - it modifies the use of `less is more` to make it clear that the author is stating a generalisation rather than a hard and fast rule.